# pandas 1.2.0 で、行ごとの加算値を求めたい

Tags: python, pandas

pythonのpandasで、ゼロ列目（行名）が日付になって、１列目以降は整数データのみのデータフレームなのですが、いままでは、
df['加算結果'] = df.sum(axis=1)
という具合に日にちごと（＝行ごと）の加算値が計算できていました。

最近、pandasをアップデートしたことが問題らしく、
TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`
というエラーが出るようになってしまいました。

計算対象のdfは、ゼロ列目が日付ですが、加算しようとしているのは２列目以降の整数値で、計算対象に日付データは含まれていません。このエラーは何が言いたいのでしょうか？「`n * obj.freq`」を使えと言っているようなのですが、意味が分かりません。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ヘルプの [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) を参考に、他者が問題を再現・調査できるソースコード(およびデータ)をテキストで提示してください。エラーメッセージについても省略せず全部を提示してください。

Comment: ちなみに [pandas.DataFrame.sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html), [Pandas DataFrame DataFrame.sum() 関数](https://www.delftstack.com/ja/api/python-pandas/pandas-dataframe-dataframe.sum-function/) に書いてある`numeric_only`パラメータを`True`で設定してみてはどうでしょう？ [数値データのみで計算する](https://deepage.net/features/pandas-sum.html#%E6%95%B0%E5%80%A4%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A7%E8%A8%88%E7%AE%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

Comment: 検証可能なサンプルデータを提示していただくと回答しやすくなります。また、今まで使用していたpandasのバージョンと現在使用しているpandasのバージョンは何でしょうか？